# Location of ApplicationContext.xml and properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my application I have placed the `ApplicationContext xml` file in src and the project is working fine.
Can we place the `ApplicationContext.xml` in our WebContent or Web-Inf folder?

Also I want to know if I can place my properties file in WebContent.

Since I have placed my `ApplicationContext.xml` in `src`, I placed my properties file in src and that worked fine. Below is the code for it

```
<bean id="licenseSettings"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:LicenseSettings.properties" />
</bean>
```

I tried putting the properties file in `WebContent/conf` but the properties were not read succesfully.

My question is, can we put ApplicationContext.xml and properties file somewhere inside WebContent folder?

**Update**: I put my ApplicationContext.xml in `WEB-INF/classes` and it was read successfully using `ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");`

My only question remaining unanswered is, where shall I put my properties file and where is it appropriate to be put in?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are **couple of ways** you can do this:

In Spring MVC, You mention `dispatcher-servlet` in `web.xml` as follows

> ```
>  <servlet>
>           <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
>             <servlet-class>
>                       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
>             </servlet-class>
>             <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> ```

Now this by default will look for a file named `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml`. That is, the servlet name appended by -servlet.xml. And it will look for this file in class path.

**Alternatively** *which fits your case*, if you already have xml file and don't want to rename it, add the following entry in web.xml **in addition** to the servlet entry above.

> ```
>  <context-param>
>     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>     <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/ApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
>  </context-param
> ```

Here you can choose any location inside WEB-INF. Put the properties file in classes folder so that it could be found in classpath. Since you are using Eclipse embedded Tomcat, put the following as your bean configuration  for property placeholder.

> ```
>  <property name="location" value="classpath:../../conf/LicenseSettings.properties" />
> ```

Comment: My `ApplicationContext` is being read properly wherever I put it but not the properties file. So that is being my main doubt.

Comment: Where are you putting your properties file? It should be in `classpath`.

Comment: I tried putting my properties file in following locations: `src` - worked, `WebContent/conf` - not working, `WEB-INF/conf` - not working.

Comment: Please put it in classes folder.

Comment: You mean in `WebContent/classes` or `src`?

Comment: Are you running this application from Eclipse embedded tomcat ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23299/discussion-between-freakyuser-and-santosh)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

If you put the files directly inside WEB-INF that should work.

If you want to put them in a folder called `WEB-INF/conf` you would need to change the properties location to refer to `conf/LicenseSettings.properties`

Comment: I put the `ApplicationContext` in WEB-INF and got this `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource ApplicationContext.xml`. However, I tried putting it in `WEB-INF/classes` the above exception wasn't thrown but it failed to read the properties file and threw this `java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource WEB-INF/conf/LicenseSettings.properties`.