# Spring application context unable to find property files under maven resources folder

Tags: java, spring, maven

[image]

I am using maven in my project & I've put `database.properties` file under
maven resources folder.

I am accessing it in spring application context

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
```

But I don't understand why I am getting this file not found error on server start.

> Could not load properties; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource
>   [database.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

To my knowledge whatever resource is put under resources folder it is added to the classpath automatically by maven.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**NOTE:** Seems like there is some problem with the M2E plugin of eclipse luna. Executed the same code in Juno & it worked fine.

Comment: Are you packaging the application?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by that, I've added my pom.xml though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499072/location-of-applicationcontext-xml-and-properties-file-in-spring  somewhat similar question.. see if that helps

Answer (score 1):

That's not enough to build a deployable war file with maven. You need at least the war plugin.  There's a thorough tutorial here:

http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-a-war-file-from-eclipse-using-maven-plugin-apache-maven-war-plugin-usage/

Your pom will look something like below, and you'll need to run mvn clean install against that.

Also I see you have a spring app, where are the spring dependencies in the pom file?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CrunchifyTutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>CrunchifyTutorial</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: I've skipped the dependencies to keep the pom short in the question. Besides I'm using m2e plugin I think that would have the compiler & resources, maven-war plugin by default. Added explicitly in pom. No luck still the same prb.

Comment: Tried in eclipse Juno, works fine there. Issue with the m2e plugin of luna.

Comment: cool.  Maybe things have changed, but I always had to add the extra plugin.